# Catalog Price Rules not working / accessing Cron.php results in 503

Tags: cron, catalog-price-rules, discount

I'm working on a store with about 80,000 skus, on a quad-core dedicated server with 12GB ram and applying a Catalog Price Rule is just not working for some reason.  No discounts show, even after i've done the following:

- Create Rule
- Status: Enabled
- Customer Groups selected
- From/To Dates created
- No Conditions set (sitewide)
- Actions - apply percentage of original price, 20 percent
- Click "Save & Apply

After a good 5 minutes, i'll get the green notification saying the rule has been applied.  I'll then proceed to flush Cache and also Re-Index. Proceeding to view the site on the front-end, It's as if nothing ever happened. Not a template issue because it's worked previously.

I was assuming it may have to do with Cron not being executed yet, so i manually have accessed Cron.php in my web browser- which hangs and eventually gives the entire site a 503 error which lasts for a couple minutes and goes away.

I've tried everything from upping Memory Limits in PHP / MySQL settings and Max_Execution_Time, and I'm at my wits end as I just can't get this to work.

Any clues?

Comment: Start by increasing your amount of RAM. 12GB is not enough for a catalogue of that size, you should have 16GB minimum, 32GB ideally.

Answer (score 1):

`cron.php` should never be executed via HTTP, even exposing it to the internet is a potential DOS target.

Your cron should only ever be executed via CLI using the `cron.sh` wrapper,

- It ensures it wont run multiple times (and commence the same process repeatedly).
- It will allow you to better control PHP memory allocation (ie. more for CLI, less for web), to reduce the risk of an OOM (out of memory) condition
- Any error messages will be printed to screen (rather than a vague 503 error)
- It prevents thread hogging and resource wastage on your web server

Comment: Got it.  Would you say that catalog price rules not applying could be that it's waiting for Cron to run on the scheduled task?  Shouldn't they apply right away?

Comment: Possibly. The cron is only really used for the reapplication of rules (or expiration of), not so much for the initial application - that's what the button in the upper right corner is for in the rule management section. I was just wanting to give a little guidance on cron best practice. Its worth installing this [extension](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) to have some visibility over what task in particular is making your cron slow. With regards to your pricing rules - check the table in the DB, if its populated correctly, your issue is indexes/cache etc. (ie. debug further)